# Deleting files that are older than one day

Tags: linux, bash

I have a server which creates several log files in the log directory. Due to this logging mechanism it eats up a lot of disk space on my server. I want to write a script that deletes all the files that are older than one day and keep the latest ones.

I am able to list the directories in sorted form using `ls -trl` command. But I am not able to understand how to remove these files. Please help.

Comment: Use [`find(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find), taking care not to shoot yourself in the foot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following command:

```
/usr/bin/find <Your Log Directory> -mtime +1 | xargs rm -f
```

`mtime` - provides the file modification time.

`+1` - indicates greater than one day.

Comment: If you are going to use pipes ensure that you use -print0 and xargs -0, otherwise you will have issues with files with whitespaces in their names

Comment: I would discourage using `find | xargs rm -f`. `find` has a `-delete` option.

Comment: `-mtime` is quirky. You probably want `+0` as with `+1` it won't count files until they  are *at least* two days old (a full day greater than 1). Or you can use `-mmin +$(( 1*24*60 ))`, which works in minutes.

Answer (score 3):

Try using rm and find command like:

```
find . -mmin +$((60*24)) -exec rm {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't want `ls`, you want `find`.

It has a neat argument, `-mtime`, that limits the results to a specific time delta, and `-exec` which allows you to provide a command to run on the results.

So for example,

```
find -mtime +10 -name "*tmp*" -exec rm {} \;
```

Does an `rm` on all files older than `10` days, with `tmp` in the name.

Oh, and be careful.

Very careful.

Answer (score 0):

`find . -mtime +1 -exec rm {} \;`

Comment: Although the code is appreciated, it should always have an accompanying explanation. This doesn't have to be long but it is expected.

Comment: I agree with that. I just left my answer uncommented, because the other answers which were posted in the same time with mine were actually the same and explained. Didn't see the point to edit mine.

Comment: -mtime is quirky. You probably want +0 as with +1 it won't count files until they are at least two days old (a full day greater than 1). Or you can use -mmin +$(( 1*24*60 )), which works in minutes.